# Angular 6 - Print pdf using arraybuffer is showing blank screen

Tags: angular

I am trying to print pdf using arraybuffer or blob in angular 6. But is showing blank pdf screen while printing / opened tab.

```js
printInvoice(invoiceCode: string): Observable<ArrayBuffer> {
    return this.http.get<ArrayBuffer>(this.API_DOMAIN + `/api/v1/data/invoice/show?invoiceCodes=${invoiceCode}`, {responseType: 'arraybuffer' as 'json'})
  }
```

```js
printInvoice(invoiceCode: string) {
    this.dataService.printInvoice(invoiceCode).subscribe(response => {
      // print file
      console.log(response);
      var blob = new Blob([response], { type: "application/pdf" });
      const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      const iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
      iframe.style.display = "none";
      iframe.src = blobUrl;
      document.body.appendChild(iframe);
      iframe.contentWindow.print();
    });
  }
```

Comment: There's nothing in the iframe when you're calling `print`. Setting the src makes an asynchronous request for the document to be loaded in the iframe. You'll need to wait for that request to complete and then print.

Comment: Thanks  joh04667 for your revert. Same code is working fine. There was some issue in pdf which was serving from server was corrupted.